# Troubleshooting a hanging `list-processes`

Tags: process, performance, subprocess

Normally I'd use `M-x list-processes` to see what Emacs is running in the background. But in this case `list-processes` *itself* hangs. What is the right thing to do in this situation?

Comment: If your OS has a task manager, you can see what subprocess are running.  E.g., on Windows it is called Task Manager (or it least that was its name in the old days); OSX 10.6.8 has Activity Monitor.app; Linux has ....???

Answer (score 1):

If this happens it means that Emacs is having trouble communicating with some subprocess. It is a good idea to leave Emacs and look at its subprocesses from the hosting operating system.

For example, on Unix this may be done with `pstree $(pidof emacs)`. This won't show which process is causing the problem, but can at least serve as a kind of sanity check.

You can also send Emacs a `SIGUSR2` signal, which will stop it from hanging and kick it into a debugger.